# Assign function to Jbutton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jtree

I have a few classes to create a very simple GUI (`JFrame`) with a few objects like a JTabbedPanel and a `JTree`. And one of the classes that creates a ribbon in the `JTabbedPanel` creates a `JButton`, that should have a function that updates the `JTree`.

I do have some getter, but I have no idea how to use the `JButton` to update something on an object that gets created in the main method (the GUI object, from where I would be able to get to the `JTree`).

How do I update something on an object that gets created in the main method in the actual class of the `JButton`?

I might have to change the structure of my project.

```
public class Gui extends JFrame{
private Ribbon ribbon;
private Status status;
public Panel panel;

public Gui(){
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("INIT TITLE");
    setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);     
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600,400));
    setVisible(true);
    try {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ribbon = new Ribbon();
    add(ribbon, BorderLayout.NORTH);        
    status = new Status();
    add(status, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    panel = new Panel();
    add(panel, JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
    //panel.setLeftComponent(panel.getTree());
    //panel.openProject();
    setVisible(true);
    panel.loadProject();
}
```

The Ribbon doesnt do a lot:

public class Ribbon extends JTabbedPane {

```
public Ribbon(){

    addTab("Home", null, new RibbonHome());
    addTab("Import", null, new RibbonImport());
    addTab("Options", null, new RibbonOptions());
}
```

}

But the Ribbon-Tab creates some buttons:

```
public class RibbonHome extends JPanel{
private JButton b1, b2, b3;

public RibbonHome(){
    b1 = new JButton("test1");
    b2 = new JButton("test2");
    b3 = new JButton("test3");
    add(b1);
    add(b2);
    add(b3);

    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
             //UPDATE the JTree 
        }
    });      

}

}
```

Comment: Good point ;) The question is: How do I update something on an object that gets created in the main method in the actual class of the JButton?

Comment: Good question.  I've edited it into the post.

Answer (score 1):

1. button.[addActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener%28java.awt.event.ActionListener%29)( main );
2. main implements [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) and provides the method [actionPerformed()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html#actionPerformed%28java.awt.event.ActionEvent%29)

Answer (score 0):

A code sample of what you are doing would make things easier, but anyway.

Probably you want to make the component you are planning to update a class member. This way, you can initialize it where it is initialized now, but still reach it from your ActionListener.

Again, this is a bit a guess on how you structured things, so if you can post a code sample, I am sure you can get a much more detailed answer.

EDIT after code sample:

You could give RibbonHome an additional private member of type Gui. I usually call it parent, so it becomes: `private Gui parent;`

In the constructor of RibbonHome, you add Gui as a parameter, this way, RibbonHome will always have access to its parent.

Also add it to the constructor of Ribbon, because you will want to pass it through there.

As a last step, you will always have to construct Ribbon with Gui as a parameter, so in Gui it will become: `ribbon = new Ribbon(this);`

As soon as you have done all of this, you can reach the JTree by the getter of you JTree on parent.

There are better solutions, since this will have as a drawback that you will never be able to construct a new Ribbon from another component than a Gui, but if you want that, you can work with interfaces.

Comment: What would be a better solution? I am fairly new to Java and would like to know, what a best practice would be.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious answer is of course to pass the reference of your `Gui` class to your `Ribbon` class, which in turn can pass it to the `RibbonHome` class.

```
public Gui{
  //...
  ribbon = new Ribbon( this );
  //...
}

public Ribbon ( Gui gui ){
  //...
  addTab("Home", null, new RibbonHome( gui ));
  //...
}

public RibbonHome( Gui gui){
  //...
  b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
      //UPDATE the JTree 
    }
  }); 
  //...
}
```

However, this ensures a very tight coupling between your different classes. I do not know what exactly you want to update on that `JTree` but the more fundamental solution might be to share a model between your different views. Your `JTree` would update itself when the model changes, and the button just updates the model.